# problemas de llenar tabla de base de datos con llaves foráneas

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

estoy intentando un simple registro de una base de datos de 5 tablas lo cual intento llenar primero la mas importante pero cuando le doy registrar no sale ningún error todo funciona pero la tabla no almacena la información.
 este es el código html:

```
     <div class="main">
          <div class="formularioEventos">
             <form action="formularioEvento.php" name="formulario" method="POST">
                 <h2>Publicacion De Evento</h2>

                 <label for="title">Titulo Del Evento:</label>
                 <input name="eventoTitulo" class="eventoTitulo" type="text"  id="title" placeholder="Ingrese El Titulo Del Evento">

                 <label for="theme">Tema:</label>
                 <input name="temaEvento" class="tema" type="text" id="theme" placeholder="Ingrese Los Temas De Que Se Hablaran En El Evento">

                 <label for="fecha">Fecha:</label>
                 <input name="fechaEvento" class="fechaEvento" type="text"  id="fecha" placeholder="Ingrese La Fecha Que Se Realizara El Evento">

                 <label for="tiempo">Tiempo:</label>
                 <input name="tiempoEvento" class="tiempoEvento" type="text"  id="tiempo" placeholder="Ingrese El Tiempo Que Durara El Evento">

                 <label for="lugar">Lugar:</label>
                 <input name="lugarEvento" class="lugarEvento" type="text"  id="lugar" placeholder="Ingrese El Lugar Donde Se Realizara El Evento">

                 <label for="contenido">Contenido:</label>
                 <textarea name="contenidoEvento" class="contenidoEvento" id="contenido" placeholder="Escriba Todo A Su Gusto Acerca Del Evento"></textarea>

                 <input name="btnE" class="enviar" id="btn" type="submit" value="Publicar">
             </form> 
         </div>

     </div>
     <footer>
         <div class="pie"> 
             <p>copyright UNERG 2018 / Decoration AzX</p>
         </div>
     </footer>
     <script src="scriptUsuario.js"></script>
 </body>
```

este es el codigo php

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['btnE'])){

     include("connect_bd.php");

     //obtenemos los valores del formulario
     $titulo = $_POST['eventoTitulo'];
     $tema = $_POST['temaEvento'];
     $fecha = $_POST['fechaEvento'];
     $tiempo = $_POST['tiempoEvento'];
     $lugar = $_POST['lugarEvento'];
     $contenido = $_POST['contenidoEvento'];
     $_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO']=0;
     //Obtiene la longitus de un string

      if($titulo=="" || $tema==""||$fecha==""||$tiempo=="" ||$lugar==""){        
          $_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO']=1;        
     }else{
         $req = (strlen($titulo)*strlen($tema)*strlen($fecha)*strlen($tiempo)*strlen($lugar)*strlen($contenido));
          //ingresamos la informacion a la base de datos
         $link->query("INSERT INTO $tablaEvento(titulo_evento,fecha,tiempo,lugar,contenido)values('$titulo','$fecha','$tiempo','$lugar','$contenido')");
         $link->query("INSERT INTO $tablaTemas(titulo_tema)values('$tema')");
          $_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO']=2;

      }
     include("cierre_Session.php");
   }
 if($_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO']==1){
     echo'<script>alert("Faltan Campos Por Rellenar");location.href="eventosPublicacion.html";</script>';
 }
 if($_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO']==2){
      echo'<script>alert("Evento Cargado Exitosamente");location.href="eventosPublicacion.html";</script>';
 }
```

?>

y la conexión a la base de datos

```
<?php
 $host ="localhost";
 $user ="root";
 $password ="";
 $bd ="bd_eventos";

 $tablaLogin="login";
 $tablaEvento="eventos";
 $tablaPonentes="ponentes_temas";
 $tablaAsistencia="asistencia_eventos";
 $tablaTemas="temas_exposiciones";


 error_reporting(1);

 $link = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$bd );

 if ($link->connect_errno){
     echo "se estan experimentando fallos...";
     exit();
 }
```

?>

y las tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agradecería mucho que me aclararan el error que esta pasando por que no he dado con una solución factible

Comment: A tu query es posible que le falten espacios de separación entre palabras y puede fallar por eso

Comment: sigue igual, eh intentado de todo pero las tablas no aceptan los datos y lo que quiero es llenar primero la de eventos, luego la de temas y de ultimo la de ponentes. respetando la relacion de muchos a muchos o uno a uno

Comment: ya resolvi yo solo el problema buscando informacion solo hay que hacer esoto a la hora de ingresar los datos $link->query("INSERT INTO $tablaEvento(titulo,fecha,tiempo,lugar,contenido,id_temas)values('$titulo','$fecha','$tiempo','$lugar','$contenido','$link->insert_id')");                      ir dejando el id desde la tabla menos hasta la mayor o mejor dicho desde las tablas hijos a padres, lo dejo por si acaso alguien tiene mi mismo problema

Comment: Hola @AZX, te recomiendo que si has encontrado la solución a tu problema lo compartas como una respuesta en vez de un comentario, de esta forma si alguien tiene el mismo problema encontrará la respuesta rápidamente.